# Oracle trigger - updating a row should update multiple rows in the same table based on condition

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I have written a trigger to update(before)  records in table based on the value of record updated

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CONTACTS_UPDATE_TRIGGER 
BEFORE UPDATE  ON CONTACTS 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF :NEW.CONTACT_TYPE= 'PRIMARY' THEN  
UPDATE CONTACTS SET CONTACT_TYPE= NULL WHERE CONTACT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY' AND HOSPITAL_ID = :NEW.HOSPITAL_ID ;
END IF;
END;
```

But getting table mutating error. Is there any other way to update other rows in table based on the values in the row updated in oracle db

Comment: This generally results in a mutating table error.  The easiest solution is to store the information in another table.

Comment: Or try making the transaction as AUTONOMOUS but highly un-recommendable or try to convert it to STATEMENT LEVEL TRIGGER rather than ROW LEVEL Trigger

Comment: if i make it statement level, will i be able to access the record that is getting updated.. Because my update query is based on the condition present in the record updated(based on the contact type of the current record)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, rather than having a trigger, I'd amend the original update statement (preferably in a stored procedure which is the only thing that can update the table, but hey-ho, YMMV) to something like:

```
update contacts
set    contact_type= case when contact_type = 'PRIMARY' then null
                          when hospital_id = :hospital_id then 'PRIMARY'
                     end
where  contact_type = 'PRIMARY'
or     hospital_id = :hospital_id;
```

And here's a test case:

**Setup**

```
create table contacts (hospital_id number,
                       contact_type varchar2(10),
                       val number);

insert into contacts (hospital_id, contact_type, val)
select 1, 'PRIMARY', 100 from dual union all
select 2, null, 200 from dual union all
select 3, null, 300 from dual;

commit;

select * from contacts
order by hospital_id;

HOSPITAL_ID CONTACT_TYPE        VAL
----------- ------------ ----------
          1 PRIMARY             100
          2                     200
          3                     300
```

**Update the primary hospital**

```
update contacts
set    contact_type= case when contact_type = 'PRIMARY' then null
                          when hospital_id = 3 then 'PRIMARY'
                     end
where  contact_type = 'PRIMARY'
or     hospital_id = 3;

commit;
```

**Results**

```
select * from contacts
order by hospital_id;

HOSPITAL_ID CONTACT_TYPE        VAL
----------- ------------ ----------
          1                     100
          2                     200
          3 PRIMARY             300
```